# Why is the power of $T$ to the fourth in Stefan's law? Any particular reason?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, thermal-radiation

Someone posed a question in front of me that why is the power of t 4 in Stefan's law? please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intuitive reason for the $T^4$ term in Stefan Boltzmann law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335122/)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46646/2451

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, thermal radiation into a 1D space (better known as [Johnson noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise)) has a [total power proportional to $T^2$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32998/3811). Thermal radiation into a 2D space is proportional to $T^3$, and into 3D space it's proportional to $T^4$. More dimensions means there are more spatial modes that you can fill with photons. This is somewhat related to the fact that the area of a circle is proportional to radius squared, while the volume of a sphere is proportional to radius cubed, and so on. I'm not sure I can give a completely satisfying answer without re-deriving the whole blackbody formula. Maybe somebody else will.

Comment: hi there. thanks a lot for your effort. This question was posed to me by a person who is in school. Can you give a more basic answer (which i can explain to him)?

Answer (score 1):

In short, if space had $D$ dimensions we would expect proportionality to $T^{D+1}$. If you want a classical argument, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law#Thermodynamic_derivation_of_the_energy_density); if you want to fix the proportionality constant, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law#Derivation_from_Planck.27s_law). (Both of those links present the $D=3$ case, but the generalisation is immediate.)